# Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have created a Nodejs server that uses Redis. It runs fine when I am running it in my machine. But I get the error above when I try to push the code to heroku. I already installed Redis togo and I can see the `REDISTOGO_URL` in my config variable.

Following some Stackoverflow posts I did:

```
let RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)

let redisClient = redis.createClient()
if(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL){
    let redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
    redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL)
}
```

My app runs fine in development but when I try to start my app in heroku I get the following error when I do `heroku logs --tail` :

> Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got that error is because you first try to create redis client with `redis.createClient()`. by default, it will connect to `127.0.0.1:6379`.

It works fine on localhost because it won't go into the `if (process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL` and the local redis is available.

To fix this,

```js
let redisClient
if(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL){
    let redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
    redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL)
} else {
    redisClient = redis.createClient()
}
```

Comment: I also had to change the variable to `REDISGO_URL`. Also I had to remove `url.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be expecting a `REDISCLOUD_URL` environment variable. If you've defined `REDISTOGO_URL` then that would explain why it isn't working.

Comment: You were right. I had to use both answers to solve the issue. Also I had to remove url.parse and do `redisClient = redis.createClient(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL)`

Answer (score 0):

Heroku requires you to provide a REDISCLOUD_URL environment variable when creating redisClient.

so you should provide the REDISCLOUD_URL while creating the Redis client.

```
let redisClient
if(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL){
    redisClient = redis.createClient(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL)
} else {
    redisClient = redis.createClient()//for running locally
}
```